# Multilple conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have over 16000 rows in excel and I have to apply some conditions on it and generate a new row with the desired result

For Excample I have cells A to to H filled with differnet values

The conditions are

```
IF ALL cells contains "A" from A1 TO H6-> THEN Print the value "A" on next column
IF ALL cells contains "D" from A1 TO H6 -> THEN Print "D"
IF ALL R -> THEN R
IF ALL U -> THEN U

IF ANYONE D THEN D
IF ANYONE R THEN R
IF ANYONE U AND OTHER A THEN A
```

How can I create formulas for this in excel please help.I have serached and found the formula for if all cells contain same text but I am specifically looking for If all cells contains this text then print this
And If any one of the cell contains this text then print this

Comment: Hint: `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:H1,"A")=8,"A","Add conditions here")`.

Comment: shrivallabha.redij can you please explain the hint? Also does this apply to all the above conditions?